# sapui5 UploadCollection - unable to set correct icon

Tags: sap-fiori

I try to use sap.m.UploadCollection to display attachments. Here is the example from Sap explored:
[image]

However, for my documents, I get always this icon:

[image]

I checked mimetype is set correctly for the item, filetype is set as well for the uploadcollection.

Do you know where is the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason:
UploadCollection icon is mapped not to the mimetype specified, but to the filename property. So if the filename is returned without extension, like "Notes" instead of "Notes.txt", then no icon is displayed.

I still do not get why sap wants to parse filename to get extension from it, where mimetype property is 100% suitable for its purpose,
but this is the solution - provide fill filename.